# content types with a rich HTML site column

Tags: sharepoint-designer

We have implemented content types with a rich HTML site column, but can't get rich text editing features (from ribbon) to work in pages when editing. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have custom developed Page Layouts?  If so, they may define special editable regions for those fields and it is possible that they make use of the wrong control type.

Answer (score 0):

In your page layout, are you displaying the Rich HTML site column with the RichHtmlField control, sample of a Page Layout declaration of this below:

```
<PublishingWebControls:RichHtmlField ID="yourRichContentControlID" FieldName="yourRichContentFieldName" runat="server"/>
```

If the above doesn't work, let us have some more details of your problem.